How do I open a site in an iframe from an extension page?
I have a Chrome extension.  On one of the extension pages I want to open an iframe where the source is not from the same source but from the extension page.
I keep getting this error:

Refused to display 'https://example.com/' in a frame because it set X-Frame-Options to sameorigin.

I understand why it is happening but when searching for a fix I run into an endless maze of "host-permissions", "permissions", "content-security-policy" on the manifest page.
Which one am I supposed to use to fix this?
I also cant figure out if I should be putting this block of code on my extensions js page or not?
const iframeHosts = [
  'example.com',
];
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  const RULE = {
    id: 1,
    condition: {
      initiatorDomains: [chrome.runtime.id],
      requestDomains: iframeHosts,
      resourceTypes: ['sub_frame'],
    },
    action: {
      type: 'modifyHeaders',
      responseHeaders: [
        {header: 'X-Frame-Options', operation: 'remove'},
        {header: 'Frame-Options', operation: 'remove'},
        // Uncomment the following line to suppress `frame-ancestors` error
        // {header: 'Content-Security-Policy', operation: 'remove'},
      ],
    },
  };
chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
    removeRuleIds: [RULE.id],
    addRules: [RULE],
 });
});


It was the second post on this question.  Getting around X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?
I am using and require a manifest version 3 solution.

The code is correct and the answer you've linked describes the changes you need to make. I don't understand where "endless maze" occurs and what you mean by "manifest page". Please show your current manifest.json. As for the code, it can be used in the background script or in the page that loads the iframe, in which case you use only the inner contents of chrome.runtime.onInstalled, and await for updateDynamicRules before adding the iframe. Also make sure to read the answer to the end where it describes how to deal with the site's service worker.

By manifest page I meant manifest.json  My current manifest.json is not doing what I intended.  Could you please tell me which keys of the file should say what.  The endless maze I was describing was an attempt to figure out what belonged in what key on the manifest.json file in a manifest version 3 extension.

The answer you've linked already shows how to edit manifest.json, but you say it's unclear, which is why I'm asking you to show your current manifest.json.

I've literally tried dozens of combinations of multiple keys in the past few hours all resulting in the same error.  How about you tell me which keys need which values?

The answer you've linked already shows how to edit manifest.json and it was used by countless people since it was posted, so apparently you didn't apply it correctly. Please show your code e.g. manifest.json, background.js, and the script of the page that embeds the iframe.

I found a solution to this, finally.  In the manifest, or the manifest.json if you want to be specific.
"declarative_net_request" : {
"rule_resources" : [{
  "id": "removeHeader",
  "enabled": true,
  "path": "remove-headers.json"
}]

}
Next a new file was needed called remove-headers.json
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
        "type": "modifyHeaders",
        "responseHeaders": [
            { "header": "x-frame-options", "operation": "remove" },
            { "header": "content-security-policy", "operation": "remove"},
            { "header": "referrer-policy", "operation": "remove"}
        ]
     },
    "condition": { "urlFilter": "https*", "resourceTypes": 
    ["main_frame","sub_frame"] }
}
]

This was issue had much more clarity after reading this github page.  https://github.com/MartinWie/Framer/tree/main

Note that this code strips the header in any tabs and frames, not just inside the extension, on all https sites covered by host_permissions in the extension's manifest.json.

You can remove undesirable headers as they arrive with a function like the one below:
In background.js...
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(info){

 var H=info.responseHeaders, N=''; // V='';

  for(let i=H.length-1; i>=0; i--){N=H[i].name.toLowerCase(); // V=H[i].value.toLowerCase();

   if((N.includes('x-frame-options'))||(N.includes('x-xss-protection'))||(N.includes('content-security-policy'))||(N.includes('report-'))){

    H.splice(i,1); 

}} return {responseHeaders:H};},{urls:['<all_urls>'],types:['main_frame','sub_frame']},['blocking','responseHeaders','extraHeaders']);

In manifest.json (version 2) you'll also need this entry if not already there...
 "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"],.....  },

NB: I get rid of a couple more headers other than X-Frame-Options so do check the script and remove what you don't want.
